# POST request not working with AJAX & Flask, giving error 415

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, post

I'm new to flask & js and have been spending the last few days tryna POST data from a form to the API.

Here's the code for the submit button in the script tags of the HTML file:

```
function onclick()  {
  var formdata = {
    "name": $("#fnamei").val(),
    "email": $("#email").val(),
    "pnum": $("#password").val(),
    "dob": $("#dob").val()
  };
  formdata = {
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {                                  //added headers later to try
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(formdata),
    body: JSON.stringify(formdata),     //added body later to try
    dataType: 'json',
    // url: "{{ url_for('login') }}"
    url: "/login"
  };
  $.ajax(formdata);
}
```

Here's the function in  the app.py file:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return request.get_json()
```

When I submit the form, I get the Error 415: Unsupported Media Type - Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'. I've mentioned the content-type multiple times so I don't understand why it's not being accepted.

Comment: You set `formdata` then you overwrite it. Before you send `formdata` in your ajax query do `console.log(formdata)` to check if that's what you're expecting to send.

Comment: Done, everything looks fine until the ajax line...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using same variable multiple times, which results in cancellation of the first declared variable. Try using the below solution.

> If still it does not work out  try to use

`data : formdata1`  . Hope this works out :)

```js
function onclick()  {
  var formdata1 = {
    "name": $("#fnamei").val(),
    "email": $("#email").val(),
    "pnum": $("#password").val(),
    "dob": $("#dob").val()
  };
  var formdata2 = {
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {                                  
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(formdata1),
    //body: JSON.stringify(formdata1),     
    dataType: 'json',
    // url: "{{ url_for('login') }}"
    url: "/login"
  };
  $.ajax(formdata2);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't make a difference :( A few details I forgot to mention - the form tag has method = "post" and there's also a script tag for jquery since I'm using ajax.